# Vue.js to display flow diagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to Vue.js library. I would like to display flow of my task ( functional representation). 
I have some sets of task running in linux box. I want to display the status of my task in UI thru API call. 
Is there any element/ widget available in Vue.js to display ? More over there is dependency between 2 task.

Answer (score 0):

It is a broad question but there are a few cool projects that do that. [Vue-diagrams](https://github.com/gwenaelp/vue-diagrams) is a not so popular one (that means that it may have some bugs) but it looks pretty neat, also [amCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/using-amcharts-vue-js-webpack/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAkfriBRD1ARIsAASKsQIc3ZdD18qbqMCqc6HxtY5mLsn38QdYFxeZ2FC2VX7wCMckElI8xhgaAvYUEALw_wcB) is a really big library that allows you to choose more types of charts. It's all up to you but those are the 2 that I find to be more interesting.